# howler "playback was unable to start"

Tags: angular, playback, howler.js

I'm creating an angular App (PWA) which need to play a list of audio file.
I'm using Howler librairy

First , I've found why it's didn't work on iOS, it's because the flag html5 of howler must be set to TRUE.

Now, I've an other issue on iOS only ! (not in MAC, Android, Windows). I can't manage to launch an other audio file when the first is finished !

Error msg : Playback was unable to start. This is most commonly an issue on mobile devices and Chrome where playback was not within a user interaction

=> Please help me to avoid that !

```
var sound = new Howl({
  src: ['/assets/fr/audio/gsp.mp3'],
  format : ['mp3'],
  html5: true
});



sound.on('end', function(){
  alert('end out');
  var sound_suite = new Howl({
    src: ['/assets/fr/audio/gsp.mp3'],
    format : ['mp3'],
    html5: true,
  });




  sound_suite.on('playerror',function(id,error){
    alert('error OP: ' + error); //<===== Error here : Playback was unable to start. This is most commonly an issue on mobile devices and Chrome where playback was not within a user interaction
  });


  sound_suite.play();
```